# Should MacVim be sourcing my ~/.zlogin?

Tags: macos, vim, zsh, macvim

When I launch MacVim - either through `mvim` command or through Finder - it sources my `.zlogin` file. For some reason - which I'm not exactly sure - the script erros out during the execution of my shell greeter and MacVim goes bananas and stops working.

So my question is: should MacVim really be sourcing my login scripts (I assume it's loading an internal instance of zsh for some reason but in that case I guess it should be a non-login shell, correct?)?

Comment: Unless your `.vimrc` is sourcing `.zlogin` explicitly, it should not be sourcing `.zlogin`.

Comment: I'm not sourcing it explicitly: https://github.com/fuadsaud/J.A.R.V.I.S/blob/master/vim/rc.vim

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "shell greeter", but it sounds like your `.vimrc` is starting a new shell instance, so you are indirectly sourcing `.zlogin` via that new shell.

Comment: It's just the program that's fired in the `.zlogin` script. I understand that `mvim` is starting a shell instance but I'd like to know if that's correct/expected and if it's not the case of my scripts being misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using the fish shell, and the solution was to explicitly set the shell in my `.vimrc`:

```
set shell=/bin/sh
```

Comment: That indeed works. It looks fine but I wonder if that'll issue any side-effects (like rbenv or other thing that need to be loaded during shell startup time stop working).